# Notation for probability: $C_n^r$, $P_n^r$, $A_n^r$?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, notation, permutations

I was told that $C^{n}_{k}$ refers to combinations or choose **k** elements from **n** elements, $\bar{C^{n}_{k}}$ refers to combinations with repetitions (i.e. $C^{n+k-1}_{k}$), and $P^{n}_{k}$ refers to ordered permutations of k elements in n.

**Question 1:** What does $A^{n}_{k}$ refer to?

**Question 2:** Is there any other notation should I be aware of to read papers on probability?

Comment: Notations, when it comes to this subject, are not very standardised. For instance, I've seen the $C^n_k$ denoted as $^nC_k$, $_nC_k$, $(n)_k$, and $\binom{n}{k}$ (where the last is the most common way of writing it, far as I can tell). The point being that it's unlikely anyone can really tell you either what a particular symbol in this family means without more context, or what else you should know. The nice thing, however, is that, given the non-standardness, people tend to define their symbols in the paper itself. Did you try looking for one in the source where $A_k^n$ was used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author used $A_{k}^{n}$ to refer to ordered premutations of k elements in n. It was from a Russian book, probably that why the different notation.